# Changing part of map (image) color on hover

Tags: jquery, css, html

I work on this project that includes regions of Croatia for search real estates. So I try to get every region on hover to change color from blue to orange. I try to go with javascipt on hover and png, but no good. I only cut image like that and get square images that go one above another. Does anybody have a idea, or work on same stuff to give me guidelines. Customer don't wont a flash.

[image: Map of Croatia]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SVG:

1) You download svg world map or Croatia map(in this case skip step 2) from that internets

2) Open it in any program that can edit svg(I prefer Adobe Illustrator) and remove all the regions except Croatia

3) Load the result svg file to your document

4) Via pure js or Jquery bind svg `polyline` or any other element you have to change its `fill` attribute on mouseenter.